# ASP NET CORE ERROR DEVELOPMENT MODE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

He publicado mi aplicacion  ASP.NET CORE MVC en IIS, pero resulta que al iniciar sesion ya sea con un usuario creado localmente o con mi cuenta de Azure, me genera el siguiente error

Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-6719bcdb3bda05a2a95b50856933bfb3-a38ce5b41854d098-00

Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.

Esta es mi clase program

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
.AddAzureAD(options =>
{
    //Llamamos cada valor de la cuenta AAD
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
    options.Domain = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Domain"];
    options.Instance = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"];
    options.TenantId = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
    options.CallbackPath = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:CallbackUrl"];

    //almacena el cookie de autenticacion usuario
    options.CookieSchemeName = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
});


builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
})
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataAccessService, DataAccessService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, AuthorizationPolicyProvider>();


//Configuracion de cookies autenticacion
builder.Services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
    options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/usuarios/Denegado";
    });

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    DbInitializer.Initialize(app);
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}



app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});

app.Run();
```

Alguna solucion al respecto?

Comment: Lo que te dice el mensaje es que no va a mostrar el error y que para ello debes configurar el sitio en modo desarrollo. Creo que en el visor de eventos (EventViewer.exe) se pueden ver algunos errores sin necesidad de lo anterior. Para configurar el modo desarrollo debes configurar el `appsettings.json` o el `web.config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que he hecho para resolver el siguiente error:

1. he creado un perfil en el archivo launchSettings.json llamado "Prod" de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. En mi clase program.cs lo he dejado de esta forma

   ```
   if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())1
   {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }
   ```

Pero cuando publico el proyecto en IIS utilizo la variable de entorno "Prod" que tambien la configuro en el webconfig

Comment: Recuerda marcar tu respuesta como aceptada luego de 24 horas de ser publicada, de este modo ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.